# how to enable and disable search bar(bootstrap4)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, searchbar

I did an angular 4 project and in the header I added a search bar, I want to know how to enable and disable the search bar when it's needed.

```
 <form *ngIf="!authService.isAnonyme()" class="navbar-form navbar-left"  role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search.." [(ngModel)]="_search"  name="srch-term" id="srch-term" >
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="Search()">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: you should not put only your problem, show us some code its help a lot to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the search bar as shown below. You have not mentioned any code or what is the condition to disable the search bar. So, here I put a validation of the value of a variable: limit. You can change it according to your need.

```
                <label class="search">
                    <i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchName" [disabled]='limit' >
                    </mat-form-field>
                </label>
```

In TS file put,

```
/* if you want to disable the field*/
    limit = true 
/* if you want to enable the field*/
    limit = false
```

Comment: i want to enable the search bar in some component and to disable it in others

Comment: Ok..but you can do that by setting value of 'limit' true or false in the components according to your need.Check the updated code. It is not that difficult to achieve.

Comment: yes, that's right it works for me thank you @Rak2018

Answer (score 0):

your answer is use in whatever component you want

```
<form *ngIf="!authService.isAnonyme()" class="navbar-form navbar-left"  role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search.." [(ngModel)]="_search" [disable]="searchSomething" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" >
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="Search()">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

in ts

```
searchSomething: boolean = false;

Search() {
   this.searchSomething = !this.searchSomething;
}
```

Comment: @itcyber I edited my answer I'm glad if its works for you